# Hook не всегда срабатывает

Tags: delphi, winapi

Имею вот такой код. Пишу глобальный перехватчик сообщений от клавиатуры.

```
library ScanFlow1;

uses Windows, SysUtils;

var
 CurrentHook: HHook;

function KeyboardProc(nCode: integer; wParam: integer; lParam: integer ): LongWord; stdcall;
begin
  if (nCode < 0) then
  begin
    Result := CallNextHookEx(CurrentHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    Exit;
  end;
  //Что то делаем  ...

  Result := CallNextHookEx(CurrentHook, nCode, wParam, lparam);
end;


procedure SetupGlobalKeyBoardHook;
begin
  CurrentHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, @KeyboardProc, HInstance, 0);
end;

procedure UnHook;
begin
  UnhookWindowshookEx(CurrentHook);
end;

exports
  SetupGlobalKeyBoardHook, UnHook;
begin
end.
```

И вижу что он срабатывает в отдельных приложениях. в Notepad ++, в браузере и некоторых других не работает, а вот в просто Notepad срабатывает. Что здесь не так? Это же глобальный хук?

Comment: Может браузер и блокнот++ ставят свои хуки и не делают `CallNextHookEx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашел в установке другой функции 
`CurrentHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, @KeyboardProc, HInstance, 0);`

```
function KeyboardProc(Code, wParam, lParam: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
var
  zKeyState: TKeyBoardState;
  zChr: Char;
  zCount: Integer;
  zHookInfo : PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(CurrentHook, Code, wParam, lParam);
  if Code <> HC_ACTION then Exit;
  zHookInfo := Pointer(lParam);
  if (zHookInfo^.flags And LLKHF_UP) <> 0 then
  begin
    GetKeyboardState(zKeyState);
    zCount :=  ToAscii(zHookInfo.vkCode, zHookInfo.scanCode, zKeyState, @zChr, 0);
    if zCount = 1 then
      if DestHandle <> 0 then
        SendMessage(DestHandle, Msg, Ord(zChr), 0);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы устанавливаете хук через [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), то третьим параметром вы [указываете описатель DLL](http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2011/09/why-does-setwindowshookex-take.html) (HMODULE/HINSTANCE). Эта [DLL будет загружена](http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2011/01/hinstance-setwindowshookex.html) в **каждый** процесс, если устанавливаемая ловушка - глобальна.

В частности, это означает, что ваша ловушка не будет работать для 64-битных процессов (подразумевая, что ваша DLL - 32-битная) - потому что [32-битную DLL нельзя загрузить в 64-битный процесс](http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2010/11/64-windows.html) (и наоборот).

Иными словами, чтобы установить действительно глобальную ловушку, вам нужно написать два приложения и две DLL - на 32 и 64 бита. И устанавливать/удалять их одновременно.

Решение с WH_KEYBOARD_LL - некорректно. Действительно, [низкоуровневые ловушки не внедряются в процесс](http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2011/01/low-level-hook.html), поэтому разрядность DLL не будет иметь значения. Но это также означает, что глобальная ловушка будет выполнятся в контексте **вашего** приложения, а не приложения, в котором происходит событие. Конечно же, такая операция с переключением контекстов имеет свою цену. Низкоуровневые ловушки очень дорогостоящи - по возможности не используйте их.